# Scale Invariant Template Matching

Tags: java, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am trying to solve the problem of template matching, wherein we have been given a pattern image I have to find whether that image exists as a sub-image inside an image i.e. source/search image.

I have implemented [SAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences) [Sum of Absolute Difference Solution using JAVA give in Wikipedia using some ]. 
Now, I want to implement a scale-invariant [template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) solution for the given problem.

Where I don't care which scale is given for a pattern image, if there is a match at a certain scale then it should report it.

Things I have tried so far: 
1. I have seen SIFT but it is too complicated to implement it.

1. Also, Image Fingerprinting used by [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/faq#how) is not that effective as it is useful in finding similar image, not sub-image.
2. I can not use exhaustive approach which I used earlier as there could be many scales at which there is a match.
3. CUSTOM APPROACH: Classify the image in several color groups e.g. 255 colors but I am not sure that would help, in scale - in-variance problem.
   I saw some questions, but they are rotation and scale invariant, I just need scale-in-variance.

It is one of the semester project, on which I am currently working on.
Can someone guide me about possible solutions and approaches that I can take?

Comment: If its a semester project, I recommend you to implement SIFT (but maybe using OpenCV, rather than JAVA, if allowed). [This](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/implementing-sift-in-opencv/) link is highly recommended.

Comment: @Parag I can not use, OpenCV because, it is not allowed, I have certain constraints for implementing this project. So,I can only use Java or Python that too built-in JDK api 1.6 thats it.

Comment: Is OpenCV not allowed because of its library or because of C language? If its the language then OpenCV using python is available [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface)

Comment: No, the prof. is trying to put constraints, so I am not allowed to use  OpenCV at all.